# Java - Finding MIN, MAX, and AVG number of comparisons using Quicksort

Tags: java, sorting, comparison

With this code, I am supposed to take a few arrays of size 2048, 4096, 8192, and 16384. Populate them with random integers from 1-1000, sort them using quick sort, then display the min, max, and avg number of comparisons based on the amount of times you want to repeat the loop.

The problem is, when I choose to only repeat this process once, the min max and avg are all the same numbers. Here is the console:

```
WELCOME TO QuickSortTest!

 Please enter how many times you would like to repeat the test: 
 1
 *************** CURRENT REPEAT: 1 ***************

 Test on array with size 2048
Before sort: 
 4392, 24, 3658, 4353, 3450, 2737, 2317, 1223, 1534, 3363, 551, 3369, 4597, 4712, 681..... 

After sort: 
2, 7, 8, 11, 13, 14, 16, 16, 23, 24, 32, 41.......

Sorted?: true

Test on array with size 4096
Before sort: 
4182, 3847, 4388, 3628, 4309, 2987, 2454, 4938, 4187, 223.....

After sort: 
2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13.....

Sorted?: true

Test on array with size 8192
Before sort: 
2795, 1531, 4347, 2122, 2015, 3900, 3198, 240, 3821...

After sort: 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 10...

Sorted?: True

Test on array with size 16384
Before sort: 
3577, 3411, 1576, 3966, 3270, 2922, 1478, 617, 3466, 3612....

Test on array with size 16384
Before sort: 
3577, 3411, 1576, 3966, 3270, 2922, 1478, 617, 3466, 361.....

Sorted?: true

Data results for array size 2048: 

    Min: 25348
    Max: 25348
    AVG: 25348.0

Data results for array size 4096: 

    Min: 60721
    Max: 60721
    AVG: 60721.0

 Data results for array size 8192: 

     Min: 121244
     Max: 121244
    AVG: 121244.0

Data results for array size 16384: 

     Min: 284787
     Max: 284787
     AVG: 284787.0
```

Now, when I input for 10 repeats, the results are different:

```
 Data results for array size 2048: 

    Min: 22856
    Max: 26858
    AVG: 24962.5

Data results for array size 4096: 

    Min: 52289
    Max: 58102
    AVG: 55973.7

Data results for array size 8192: 

    Min: 116986
    Max: 131413
    AVG: 124013.6

Data results for array size 16384: 

    Min: 272162
    Max: 322172
    AVG: 287152.9
```

**This is my code :**

```
import java.util.*;

public class QuickSortTest {

static int qcount = 0,k = 0;
static int[] size;
static int[][] stats;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("WELCOME TO QuickSortTest!\n");
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter how many times you would like to repeat the test: ");
    k = console.nextInt();
    int[] size = {2048, 4096, 8192, 16384};
    stats = new int[4][k]; //[sizeArray][totalRepeats]

    for (int j = 1; j <= k; j++) {

        System.out.println("*************** CURRENT REPEAT: " + j + " ***************");

        for (int s = 0; s < size.length; s++) {//size array
            qcount = 0;
            int[] a = new int[size[s]];
            populateArray(a);
            System.out.println("\nTest on array with size " + (size[s]) + "\nBefore sort: ");
            print(a);
            quicksort(a, 0, a.length - 1);
            System.out.println("After sort: ");
            print(a);
            System.out.println("Sorted?: " + verifySort(a));
            stats[s][j - 1] = qcount;
            qcount=0;
        }
    }

    getData(size);
}

/*
Retrives data based on camparisons. Calculates min, max, and average comparison
*/
private static void getData(int[] a){
    for(int q = 0; q < a.length; q++){
        System.out.println("\nData results for array size " + a[q] +": ");
        int sum = 0; double average = 0.0;

        for(int x = 0; x < k; x++){
            quicksort(stats[q], 0, stats[q].length-1);
            sum += stats[q][x];
            average = (double)sum/k;
        }
        System.out.println("\n\tMin: " + stats[q][0] +
                            "\n\tMax: " + stats[q][stats[q].length-1] +
                            "\n\tAVG: " + average);
    }
}
/*
CHECKS IF ARRAY IS SORTED
*/
public static boolean verifySort(int[] a){
    boolean sorted = true;
    for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] < a[i-1]){
            sorted = false;
        }
    }
    return sorted;
}

/*
 * QUICK SORT
 */
private static void quicksort(int[] a, int bottom, int top) {
    if (bottom < top) {
        int p = partition(a, bottom, top);
        quicksort(a, bottom, p - 1);
        quicksort(a, p + 1, top);
    }
}

private static int partition(int[] a, int bottom, int top) {
    //Keeps track of what is being switched
    int save = a[bottom];

    while (bottom != top) {
        while (bottom < top && save <= a[top]) {
            top--;
            qcount++;
        }
        if (bottom != top) {
            //swap
            a[bottom] = a[top];
        }

        //Moves bottom until finding value > save/top
        while ((bottom < top) && (save >= a[bottom])) {
            qcount++;
            bottom++;
        }
        if (bottom != top) {
            //swap
            a[top] = a[bottom];
        }
    }
    a[bottom] = save;
    return bottom;
}

/*
Prints the array being passed through
*/
private static void print(int[] a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(a[i]);
        if (i < a.length - 1) {
            System.out.print(", ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
}

/*
 * Create an array of type int and populate with random
 * numbers
 */
private static void populateArray(int[] a) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        a[i] = rand.nextInt(5000) + 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Are these results normal? I'm just trying to find the one run through where it used the minimum number of comparisons, the max, and average of all run throughs based on the repeats.

Are the places where I place qcount wrong? Qcount is the counter for the amount of comparisons. Or is the way I store the data in the 3d array wrong? The way I access them? The getData() method wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I guess that your problem has something to do with  static int[][] stats; You should try to avoid to use static variables for these purposes. Try to use local variables.

Comment: @JFMeier that's what I am guessing too... I'm just trying to figure out how to fix it

Comment: Remove the static variables on top of your program and use local variables instead. If you need your variables in different methods, pass them as parameters.

Comment: @JFMeier Still doing the same thing when I set k to 1 (for the repeats)

Comment: Sorry, I do not get what you say. Have you worked on the static variables?

Comment: If there's a problem, it's not because of the usage of static variables. For this type of test, using static instead of locals is better because you don't have to pass references to the static variable which would mean changing the parameter interface of all the functions that use them. As for quicksort min / max / avg, with random data, I wouldn't expect to see much difference. Try a test with data already in order and in reverse order to see if that results in worst case situation.